# Win2008R2 Firewall will accept incoming connections from WAN but not from LAN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

We have a Windows 2008R2 server that suffered a power failure a few days ago.
The server is working fine but we are experiencing something strange:

- When the Firewall is on, the server becomes inaccessible from the LAN and all packets are dropped (doesn't even reply to pings from the LAN).
- Strangely, I have a few services configured in the firewall to accept connections from external WAN IPs. These, forwarded by the router, work normally.

In short, I can access the server from home, but not from the LAN at the office.

I had to deactivate the incoming firewall rules to allow access to the server from the LAN, but I would really like to fix that.

#### More details

1. The Network is correctly configured and NLA has correctly identified the firewall profile as "Private Network":
   [image: firewall summary]
2. The Firewall properties are correctly set:
   [image: Firewall Properties]
3. The services accessible from the outside world have their rule configured like this:
   [image: Firewall rule]

So the real issue here is why does the firewall now suddenly blocks all LAN traffic?

Comment: Is there anything else somewhere in the system that might have changed?

Comment: @Davidw it's what I am wondering. I can't see anything strange in the firewall configuration itself, and the rest of the server is working fine. When the firewall is Off, access to the server is working fine. When the firewall is on, access to the server doesn't work, even though the firewall rules allow this.

Comment: Is logging enabled, and have you looked at the firewall logs?

Comment: @Davidw The firewall logs show that the LAN packets are dropped, but there is no indication of which rule was triggered. Is there a way to actually debug the firewall in windows?

Comment: Try Netsh wfp capture start at an elevated command prompt: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428146%28v=ws.10%29.aspx